# Class level request mapping with placeholder not resolving in Spring 4

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I have spring profiles for dev and prod environments defined in **root.xml**  below:-

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

<bean id="dataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource"
    destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClass" value="${driver_class}" />
    <property name="jdbcUrl" value="${dbURL}${dbHostName}:${dbPort}/${dbName}?serverTimezone=${dbTimezone}" />
    <property name="user" value="${username}" />
    <property name="password" value="${password}" />
    <property name="initialPoolSize" value="${initial_pool_size}" />
    <property name="minPoolSize" value="${dbPoolMinSize}" />
    <property name="maxPoolSize" value="${dbPoolMaxSize}" />
    <property name="idleConnectionTestPeriod" value="50" />
    <property name="numHelperThreads" value="${numHelperThreads}" />
    <property name="maxIdleTime" value="2500"></property>
    <property name="testConnectionOnCheckout" value="true"></property>
    <property name="preferredTestQuery" value="select 1"></property>
</bean>

<beans profile="dev">
    <context:property-placeholder
        ignore-resource-not-found="false"
        location="classpath*:/META-INF/dev-database.properties,
                    classpath*:/META-INF/app.properties" />
</beans>
<beans profile="prod">
    <context:property-placeholder
        ignore-resource-not-found="false"
        location="classpath*:/META-INF/prod-database.properties,
                    classpath*:/META-INF/app.properties" />
</beans>
```

My **servlet-context xml** is as below:-

```
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.2.xsd">

<annotation-driven />
<default-servlet-handler />

<resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

<resources mapping="/javascripts/*.js" location="/resources/javascripts/" />
<resources mapping="/javascripts/cloudinary/*.js" location="/resources/javascripts/cloudinary/" />
<resources mapping="/stylesheets/*.css" location="/resources/stylesheets/" />
<beans:bean
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
    <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</beans:bean>

<context:component-scan base-package="com.free.muft" />

<beans:bean id="multipartResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">
    <beans:property name="maxUploadSize" value="10000000" />
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="messageSource"
    class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <beans:property name="basename" value="classpath:messages" />
    <beans:property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8" />
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="sessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <beans:property name="hibernateProperties">
        <beans:props>
            <beans:prop key="hibernate.dialect">${dbDialect}</beans:prop>
            <beans:prop key="hibernate.show_sql">${show_sql}</beans:prop>
            <beans:prop key="hibernate.autoReconnect">true</beans:prop>
            <beans:prop key="hibernate.autoReconnectForPools">true</beans:prop>
            <beans:prop key="hibernate.transaction.factory_class">org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransactionFactory</beans:prop>
            <beans:prop key="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size">30</beans:prop>
            <beans:prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">${hbm2ddl}</beans:prop>
        </beans:props>
    </beans:property>
    <beans:property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <beans:property name="packagesToScan">
        <beans:list>
            <beans:value>com.test.entities</beans:value>
        </beans:list>
    </beans:property>
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <beans:property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</beans:bean>

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
```

I can pull up the properties defined in these property files. These properties are getting resolved for the xml file placeholders. I want to use a property in the request mapping at class level as shown below which is not working for me:-

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("${home.url}")
public class CategoryController {
```

Is there a way to achieve it?

Edit:- This is what I'm getting in startup logs

> INFO: Mapped "{[/${home.url}/test],methods=[GET]}"

PS:- I'm using Spring version 4.3.3.

Comment: Can this be done?

Comment: Are you using <mvc:annotation-driven /> in your spring configuration file?

Comment: yes, this can be done. Do check if the the property `home.url` is available in properties file and moreover move the properties file outside `META-INF` to `src/main/resources` or any of its sub-folder

Comment: @SatyendraKumar, Yes I'm.

Comment: It should work as long as you are using <mvc:annotation-driven /> instead of old way (directly using bean definition of DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping). I can provide a working sample code if you like.

Comment: @SatyendraKumar, please do, that would be very helpful. Thanks.

Comment: @SatyendraKumar, I have updated question with more details. I made the changes as described in the answer but still it is not working...

Answer (score 1):

Controller:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("${hello.url}")
public class DynamicController {

  @Value("${hello.url}")
  String helloUrl;

  @PostConstruct
  public void postConstruct(){
     System.out.println("postconstruct: "+helloUrl);
  }

  @RequestMapping("${hello.url}")
  public String get(){
     return "GET";
  }
}
```

applicationContext.xml:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
   xsi:schemaLocation="
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">
   <context:property-placeholder
        ignore-resource-not-found="false"
        location="classpath*:/META-INF/app.properties" />
   <context:component-scan base-package="xxx" />
   <mvc:annotation-driven/>
</beans>
```

Put `app.properties` in folder src/main/resources/META-INF if you are using maven.

Comment: Still the property is not getting resolved. This is what I'm getting in the logs
`postconstruct: ${home.url}`

Comment: I would suggest start fresh from this working sample and then incrementally add your other configurations like profile and other beans, because it's hard to debug just by looking at code